# Database design table definition

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design

I am currently trying to create a database diagram for an existing database using VISIO. There are some tables (not temporary tables) which are created inside the stored procedure (dropped and created every time when the stored procedure runs). Do i need to include those tables in database diagram?

Comment: i think there will be no answer like "yes definitely" or "no definitely"..If you want and if they are important to understand the whole picture - you can. But there is no rule that you MUST include such tables in a diagram. my personal opinion: if they are not related with other tables and they only exist while SP is executing: No, i would not include them in the diagram

Comment: I think No. You can think of them like temp tables so no need to include them.

Comment: Stored procedures creating permanent tables is usually a sign of bad design. I'd spend less time worrying about the diagram and more time fixing it (by either switching to temp tables or making the tables genuinely permanent and changing how the stored proc interacts with them).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. all tables except one are not related to another tables. so i can exclude them.